# Detect pseudo CSS activation

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a DIV with the following CSS code attached:

```
   .active,#foo:active {background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75)}
```

In addition, I have set up keydown and keyup javascript routines to convert a selected keypress to add and remove the 'active' class, darkening it accordingly.  My problem is when the user clicks on the DIV (darkening it as expected)...but in a setInterval I have running, polling the DIV and several more like it periodically to get state information, I run into the problem of not being able to tell the current DIV state.

Getting the state via the active class is easy enough.  I simply have to do this...

```
document.getElementById("foo").classList.contains("active")
```

That gives me a boolean on/off I can use, but the following does not work to read a mouse long click.

```
document.getElementById("foo").classList.contains(":active")
```

This is because activated pseudoes do not show up in classList.  I tried rewriting the mouse-examining check to look like this:

```
document.getElementById("foo") === document.activeElement
```

But as the element is a DIV, this never resolves to a true as document.activeElement stays stuck on the BODY element of the page.  I also tried looking at the current background-color, but the following doesn't update when :active is in use.

```
document.getElementById("foo").style.backgroundColor === "rgba(0,0,0,0.75)"
```

Is there another way to proceed without needing to resort to removing :active from the CSS and installing onclick() and onmouseout() to my code?  Using that particular workaround does not scale well depending on how many DIVs I set up in this fashion.  I would much rather detect when the DIV is currently using the CSS rule described above.

Please, no jQuery solutions or external libraries.  I want to use vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: I don't think you can. Pretty sure all you can use is `activeElement` and per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement  `Returns the currently focused element, that is, the element that will get keystroke events if the user types any.` I don't think that's possible. Might be if you set `contenteditable` on the element? Doesn't seem like that's what you're looking for tho. I would just use `mouseup` and `mousedown` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyBrLZ

Comment: It is quite likely that you don't need JS at all, and certainly not polling. Could you provide a concise, high-level description of the behavior you are trying to implement? Then maybe someone could suggest how to do it in pure CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo elements are not part of the DOM so you cannot trigger events on them.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

In addition .style prototype function does not work as intended, to look for computed style use

```
var ele = document.querySelector('.example-value')
window.getComputedStyle(ele, null).backgroundColor === "rgba(0,0,0,0.75)"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: OP's not using a pseudo element, they're using a pseudo *class* and pseudo classes are supported in JS, sometimes, like they said using `document.activeElement`

Answer (score 0):

#### Polling to get the current state of an element is a bad idea, instead use events.

<sup>When polling, you are making CPUs always process for nothing, it can make your page irresponsible, cause useless bottlenecks, but most of all, it consumes a lot of electricity for nothing. Always think about the trees when coding.</sup>

But one has to admit that for the `:active` status, it may be a bit cumbersome to listen to all the events that can trigger it.

So we've got to be a bit smarter, and create our own event from there.

We can create an empty animation triggered only in the `:active` state.
Then we just have to listen for the [`animationstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationstart) event to act as an replacement for our pseudo-class activation event.

```js
/* older browsers might need vendor prefixes... */
foo.addEventListener('animationstart', function(evt){
  // to be sure it's our correct event, we check for the animationName
  console.log('active', evt.animationName === 'active');
  });
```

```css
#foo:active{
  background-color: #FAFFAA;
  
  -webkit-animation: active 0s linear;
  -o-animation: active 0s linear;
  -ms-animation: active 0s linear;  
  animation: active 0s linear;
  }
@keyframes active{}
@-webkit-keyframes active{}
@-o-keyframes active{}
@-ms-keyframes active{}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  click me to activate me
</div>
```

---

And if ever you need to know at any time if an element has an pseudo-class, you can use [`Element.matches(cssRule)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/matches).

Answer (score 0):

The word "active" has different meanings:

1. An element with the [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:active) pseudo-class. This means the element is **in the process of being clicked**, usually. This is most commonly used for creating some visual effect when the user mouse-downs on a button, and remove it when he mouse-ups, for example. This is probably not relevant to your use case.
2. The element given by [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement). This does **not** mean the element with the `:active` pseudo-class; it means the element with **focus**. It will be the body if there is no specific focus, or it could be some input element, or it could be any other element with a [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute. This is also the element with the [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) pseudo-class. An element can be focused by clicking on it, or tabbing to it, or calling [`HTMLElement#focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) on it.
3. Some application-defined concept of "active", such as the currently active tab in a tabbed interface, often represented by the presence of a user-defined class on the element, such as your `.active`.

In general, people write far too much JavaScript to check things, or intercept events, or set magic variables, or add and remove classes or even local styles, or in the worst jQuery style add and remove elements from the DOM, or God forbid do polling, when in many cases CSS could handle what needs to be done if used properly. A trivial example is writing `mouseover` handlers when `:hover` could do the job.

I don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish, or what the desired behavior is. However, the following code might give you some clues:

```js
const activeElement = document.getElementById("activeElement");
const divElement = document.getElementById("div");

function showActiveElement() { 
  activeElement.textContent = document.activeElement.tagName;
}

function updateActiveElement() { setInterval(showActiveElement, 500); }

function setFocus() { divElement.focus(); }

updateActiveElement();
```

```css
/* Show a message if the div is active (being clicked on). */
#activeMessage { display: none; }
#div:active ~ #activeMessage { display: block; }

/* Show a message if the div is focused. */
#focusMessage { display: none; }
#div:focus ~ #focusMessage { display: block; }

/* Style the div when it is focused. */
#div:focus { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); color: white; }

#div { border: 1px solid gray; }
```

```html
<p>
  Here is the div we are working with.
  Click on it, or tab to it, to give it the focus.
</p>

<!-- The div in question. Give it a tabindex to allow focus. -->
<div id="div" tabindex="1">
  Hello Bob
</div>

<p id="activeMessage">
  The div is active, in the sense that the mouse is being clicked on it, and
  therefore its <tt>:active</tt> pseudo-class is set.
</p>

<p id="focusMessage">
  The div is active, in the sense that it has the focus, 
  therefore its <tt>:focus</tt> pseudo-class is set.

<p>
  The element with focus at the moment (<tt>document.activeElement<//tt>) is
  <span id="activeElement"></span>
</p>

<button onclick="setFocus()">Make the div focused ("active")</button>
```

Comment: You would win in your demonstration if you didn't yourself had to use this "*God forbids polling"* (moreover when there is an simple and bubbling event to catch what's being checked). And while this answers provides correct and useful informations as to why one might not need to detect this `:active` state, it doesn't provide a way to detect it either. Let's say I want to know how much long people do hesitate while clicking on your setFocus button, I need to get an event to talk to my js, css won't let it know by itself.

Comment: @Kalido I have to admit I do not fully understand your comment. Are you complaining about my choice of words when discussing polling? Can you even tell from the OP's question that he really wants to detect some element entering the `:active` state--that's not at all clear, since he refers to the `activeElement` on the document, which has nothing to do with any `:active` state, as I mentioned. In any case, I made no claims that there are no situations requiring JS. Of course there are. I was merely pointing out that **often** people jump to JS when they don't need to.

Comment: No my *complain* if any, is just that in the text of your answer you present polling as evil (on which we do agree), but in your snippet, you are using polling to update the currently focused element logger. And about OP's wills, I have no idea either, when we see the accepted answer.

Comment: I am using polling only as a didactic device in the example to display the current `document.activeElement`, not as a solution to any real-world problem (not that I understand what the real-world problem the OP is trying to solve is).

Comment: I know this but your points would win by not doing so. Moreover when there is an event (`focus`) which does bubble (to a common ancestor of all your nodes) that you can listen to in order to get what you are checking for (the currently focused element). Why do what you said should not be done when you absolutely don't have to ?